# Group single solr facet field into ranges or bucket

Tags: solr

For a facet Solr search that returns multiple `facet.field`, is there a way to group one of those fields into ranges?

For example:

```
'facet': true,
'facetJson': {},
'facet.query': query,
'facet.mincount': 1,
'facet.field': ['field1', 'field2'],
```

For `field2`, it returns lots of different numbers, and I'd like to group it into buckets:

```
[0]: 50,
[1 - 1000]: 75,
[1001 - 5000]: 80
```

I see there's a `facet.range=field2`, but unsure of how I'd use this multiple times for 2+ different field ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use the syntax `<field>.facet.<property>`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/faceting.html#field-value-faceting-parameters) to give specific properties for each field (or you can use the JSON Facet API).

However, since you want arbitrary ranges (and not even intervals), you'll have to use `facet.query` instead of `facet.range`:

```
facet.query=field2:0&
facet.query=field2:[1 TO 1000]&
facet.query=field2:[1001 TO 5000]&
facet.query=field2:[5001 TO *]
```